# Print the visible name of a drop down menu instead of its value name

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post, drop-down-menu

Okay so here is where my problem is occurring. I have a set of code right here:

```
$gSelect = $_POST['location'];

echo"<table>";
echo "<tr><th>Year</th><th>Time</th><th>$gSelect</th></tr>";
```

This sets up a columned table that allows data to be displayed in a neat fashion once the users select their data restrictions. All of these restrictions are within drop down menus. $gSelect represents the drop down menu where users can select a location (Local Oh Counties, Ohio, US). Here is the drop down menu I am talking about:

```
    <p>
<label for="location">
Please specify a location
</label>

<select name='location'>
<option value ='Fayette'> Fayette County (IN) </option>
<option value ='Randolph'> Randolph County (IN) </option>
<option value ='Rush'> Rush County (IN) </option>
<option value ='Union'> Union County (IN) </option>
<option value ='Wayne'> Wayne County (IN) </option>
<option value ='INCounties'> Local Indiana Counties </option>
<option value ='Indiana'> Indiana </option>
<option value ='Butler'> Butler County (OH) </option>
<option value ='Darke'> Darke County (OH)</option>
<option value ='Mercer'> Mercer County (OH) </option>
<option value ='Preble'> Preble County (OH) </option>
<option value ='OHCounties'> Local Ohio Counties </option>
<option value ='Ohio'> Ohio </option>
<option value ='US'> United States </option>
</select>
</p>
```

As you can see, the option value names (which are equal to some of my columns in my database) are different from the actual names that show up in my drop down menu ('Rush' versus "Rush County (IN) for instance). Echo "$gSelect"; prints the option value name for the selection. Instead, I want it to print the name that shows up in my drop down menu. Is there anyway I can fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, I use $gSelect to set up a query to select the column for my database as well (SELECT $gSelect from table; for example), so I would like to leave $gSelect alone if possible.

Would anything like this work?

```
echo"<table>";
echo "<tr><th>Year</th><th>Time</th><th>$_POST['Location[name]']</th></tr>";
```

I am just trying to figure out how to display the drop down menu name instead of the value name without changing $gSelect since I use it in queries.

Comment: same question different name? lol you asked this 3 hours ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642090/how-to-include-a-forms-name-into-a-table-instead-of-its-name-of-value

Comment: The solution wasn't what I was looking for and I don't know how to update the question.

Comment: That doesn't mean you should create a new question. Behind the question there's an "edit" button, besides the "share" button. You should use that, I'll flag this

Comment: Actually, you can delete this question yourself also.

Comment: Share sends the question to social media. So what am I supposed to do if my previous question doesn't even get answered?

Answer (score 0):

Before doing $gSelect = $_POST['location']; you should create an array like this one:

```
$cities=["Fayette"=>"Fayette County (IN)",
        "Randolph"=>"Randolph County (IN)",
        "Rush"=>"Rush County (IN)",
        "Union"=>"Union County (IN)",
        "Wayne"=>"Wayne County (IN)",
        "INCounties"=>"Local Indiana Counties",
        "Indiana"=>"Indiana",
        "Butler"=>"Butler County (OH)",
        "Darke"=>" Darke County (OH)",
        "Mercer"=>"Mercer County (OH)",
        "Preble"=>"Preble County (OH)",
        "OHCounties"=>"Local Ohio Counties",
        "Ohio"=>"Ohio",
        "US"=>"United States",
        ];
```

then do a foreach and check if the $_POST['location']; matches any positions of the array, if yes, the show the content.